# How to use the --profile option with "aws logs" command for the CloudWatch Logs Agent?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-cloudwatch

After installing the CloudWatchLogs Agent the command

`/var/awslogs/bin/aws logs push --config-file /var/awslogs/etc/awslogs.conf --additional-configs-dir /var/awslogs/etc/config`

is running on the machine.
To use separate credentials for the CloudWatchLogs Agent a profile was created in `/root/.aws`.

Trying to use the profile with

`/var/awslogs/bin/aws logs push --config-file /var/awslogs/etc/awslogs.conf --additional-configs-dir /var/awslogs/etc/config --profile awslogs`

throws an error

`aws: error: argument operation: Invalid choice, valid choices are ...`

Comment: what are the valid choices?

Comment: it lists all the _subcommands_ of the command _cloudwatch_ like `create-log-group`, `create-log-stream`, ..

Comment: `push` is not a valid choice. Why are you using it?

Comment: `push` is valid, because this command runs successfully:
`/var/awslogs/bin/aws logs push --config-file /var/awslogs/etc/awslogs.conf --additional-configs-dir /var/awslogs/etc/config`

Comment: The above command is copied from `/var/awslogs/bin/awslogs-agent-launcher.sh`.

Comment: Can you paste the complete error message?

Answer (score 0):

`export AWS_PROFILE=user1` can be used for Linux and you can omit `--profile` in aws cli command.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-profiles.html